# How can I create a web page with a countdown timer in Python3?

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x

I need to create a web page with a countdown timer.  The below doesn't work, because the web page halts until after the countdown completes.  It doesn't update the page every second, and it also does not place the values in the  properly.  It scrolls them.  How can I get this to work?  Alternately, I believe I could embed javascript into the Python code, but I have not firgured out how to do this.  Everything I have fund in the web concerning calling a javascript from Python seems very arcane, and I can't figure it out, at all.

index.html:

```
div.Countdown {
    position: fixed;
    top: 26;
    left: 480;
    width: 300px;
    font: bold 24px Arial;
    color: black;
}
</STYLE>
```

index.cgi:

````
import time

print( '</b></h2></table></p>')
def countdown(t):
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print( '<div id="Countdown">')
        print(timeformat, flush=True)
        print('</div>')
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
    print('Goodbye!\n\n\n\n\n')


countdown(4)

print( '</BODY>')
print( '</HTML>')```
````

Answer (score 1):

You've missed something fundamental about the way the web works-- there's a *client* and a *server*. Usually but not always, the client is running on a different machine than the server. In conventional contexts, the client submits a request to the server, to which the server responds. The client waits until the server has finished responding before it attempts to render the response.

The issue you are running into is that your HTML isn't finished rendering until your while loop has completed, so the client won't render anything until your timer has reached zero.

I wouldn't recommend accomplishing this task in python at all, which only runs on the server. It's literally possible but only by very convoluted means. I would instead use a different language called javascript which runs on the client. If you're using chrome you can right click this web page, and select the "inspect" option:

[image]

Once there you can experiment with JavaScript by selecting the console option from the top of the developer console.

This looks like an tutorial on how to create a timer at an appropriate level for someone starting out: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-countdown-timer-using-javascript/

Comment: I understand very well the client / server distinction, and I understand how it relates to the web server / browser relationship.  I also am aware of javascript, although I cannot say I would be able to actually write any.  I have also looked at many different countdown timers in javascript.  Getting some code to do a countdown timer is not the issue.  The issue is I need my Python code (writing the main code in javascript is not an option - this MUST be server-side) to generate a web page with a countdown timer displayed on the browser.

Comment: Either during this process or else after each clock tick the main code will do some calculations, and then write additional data to the web page.  Honestly, I don't know that embedded javascript will work, but hypothetically the javascript process and the main body can be asynchronous, as long as the javascript returns control to the calling process in Python when complete.

Comment: I have looked at a number of different potential solutions, including calling javascript via pageObj.contentDocument.Script.function() and using websockets, but none of the documentation makes enough sense to me to be able to write functional code.  Like just about every reference I have found, your link only shows how to create a javascript timer in a flat web page.  That is trivial.  I need to create one from a Python CGI script.

Comment: I am not running Chrome.

Comment: what is motivating your requirements?

Comment: The system is an 8 port relay some of whose elements are selected to each be turned off for a specified amount of time.  After being triggered, I need to be able to monitor the status of each port, the amount of time remaining (if any) for each element to be off, and the total time remaining until the routine completes.  Thus, in actual fact, there may be as many as 9 timers running initially.  Once the main timer reaches zero, the web page will bring up the default web page, index.cgi.

Comment: you can’t have dynamic content on the webpage without javascript.